# Freebase api python

Tags: python, freebase

I have been trying to play around with the Freebase python api as mentioned here (http://code.google.com/p/freebase-python/wiki/GettingStarted). However it seems to throw some message like this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/freebase-1.0.6-py2.6.egg/freebase/api/session.py", line 626, in mqlread
    r = self._httpreq_json(service, 'POST', form=dict(query=qstr), headers=headers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/freebase-1.0.6-py2.6.egg/freebase/api/session.py", line 442, in _httpreq_json
    resp, body = self._httpreq(*args, **kws)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/freebase-1.0.6-py2.6.egg/freebase/api/session.py", line 428, in _httpreq
    return self._http_request(url, method, body, headers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/freebase-1.0.6-py2.6.egg/freebase/api/httpclients.py", line 60, in __call__
    body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/freebase-1.0.6-py2.6.egg/freebase/api/cookie_handlers.py", line 187, in request
    (r, body) = Http.request(self, uri, headers=headers, **kws)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1129, in request
    (response, content) = self._request(conn, authority, uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 901, in _request
    (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 871, in _conn_request
    response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/httplib.py", line 988, in getresponse
    method=self._method)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/httplib.py", line 330, in __init__
    self.fp = sock.makefile('rb', 0)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'makefile'
```

Comment: What code are you using to call the Python library?

Comment: the first one...whenever i am trying to use freebase.mqlread(query) this message crops up...

Comment: The first example from that page works fine for me.  There's really no way to tell what you're doing wrong with the amount of information you've provided.

Comment: That's the point...i just imported freebase, gave the query string and then mqlread...What other mistakes could be there ? The import works fine but as soon as i invoke mqlread this thing crashes..

Comment: This is the cryptic error that older versions of httplib2 return when a connection is refused. Where are you running this code? Can you test whether your machine has access to the Freebase servers?

Comment: I tried accessing the servers by running a simple script which lists the album mentioned here (http://bit.ly/GWPizz) and this works fine...maybe there is some bug in the the libraries ? Any issues with python 2.6 ? That is the version i am using.

Comment: I guess there's a bug in the library. I'm getting the same error, repeatedly!